# delete framebufferobject from different but shared context

Tags: multithreading, opengl

I have a few opengl contexts, which are created from the mainthread directly at the beginning of the program. At that time they also get shared with the **wglShareLists(contextItem.hglrc, hglrc);** command. I also have a lot of threads, each of the threads gets one context with the **wglMakeCurrent(hdc, m_vUsingContexts[i].hglrc);** command.

Now I only want to know, if I have **thread1** which is linked to **context1** and **thread2** which is linked to **context2** and both are shared. Is it possible, that **thread1** creates a framebufferobject and **thread2** deletes this framebufferobject? (Yes or No is quite enough)

I know that this is absolutely stupid to do. Usually the thread which is creating something also should delete **only** his own stuff. But I'm not able to change that, because it is a directx 11 program and I'm only program the openGL driver for it. In directx 11 it does not matter which thread is creating or deleting.

Can I also do the same with vertexbufferobjects and textures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Framebuffer objects are [container objects](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Container_Object) and therefore are not [shared](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Object#Object_Sharing) across contexts. So no, you may not delete FBOs themselves. Indeed, you cannot access them *in any way* across contexts, since they are not shared.

However, Texture and Renderbuffer objects can be shared across contexts. So you can delete them in another context. Not that this will necessarily free up memory, of course. By the rules of [OpenGL's context model](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Memory_Model#Multiple_threads_and_contexts), the objects will continue to exist so long as they are attached or bound to something else.

Object destruction needs to be managed very carefully when using multiple contexts.